# In asp.net, I need to add validator to textbox that forces the input to be numbers

Tags: asp.net, validation

In asp.net, I need to add a validator to a textbox that forces the input to be numbers.

Is this built in?

I have already added a required field validator to the textbox.

Comment: Numbers or digits?  There is a difference.

Comment: Joel, what is the difference?

Comment: @Blankman presumably he means the difference between "digits", the 10 characters representing 0-9 and "numbers", being comprised of digits, commas, decimal points, base identifiers etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="numbersOnlyTextBox" 
            ErrorMessage="Enter only numeric characters." 
            ValidationExpression="^\\d+$" />
```

Comment: ValidationExpression="^\\d*$"

Comment: Thanks, It actually should be + instead of * since there is a requirement for it to be non-empty.

Comment: @ChrisBallance The RegularExpressionValidator ingores empty imput, so there will be no difference between * and + (unfortunately)

Answer (score 7):

You could use a Regex Validator to ensure the text is numeric

I think the regex would be

```
[0-9]*
```

e.g.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxNumbers" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revNumericValidator" runat="server" 
                ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$" ControlToValidate="tbxNumbers" ErrorMessage="Must be Numeric" />
```

**EDIT:**
As the other two posters also pointed out you can also use `\d` to represent a Numeric Character

Comment: Note that + rather than the * also makes the required field validator redundant.

Comment: I like regex, but think it is overkill in this case; a range validator would be more "efficient", since you could easily permit decimals and so on, depending on the Type attribute you use.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn... I'm fairly sure it doesn't. A + means 1 or More characters however the example i gave there with a simple button click will validate on an empty textbox. I think the regex validator only kicks in for a .Text Length > 1

Answer (score 2):

Use a range validator.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" MaxLength="4" Width="75" 
   Text="0" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="MyRangeValidator"  Display="Static" Type="Integer"
   MaximumValue="9999" MinimumValue="0" EnableClientScript="true" 
   ControlToValidate="MyTextBox" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" 
   ErrorMessage="Ooops"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

This permits you to use numbers with decimal places (by using Type="Double" or "Currency"), or other kinds of numbers that Windows recognizes.

Check MSDN for more info on the [Range Validator Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think there needs to be more clarification of the requirements here. What kind of numbers are we talking about? Positive integers? Any integer? A number with a decimal place? What about commas in the number (1,000)?

I recommend a RegularExpressionValidator to do your work, but these questions make a difference when it comes to which RegEx you use.

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide a better user experience, another thing to add is an AjaxToolkit FilteredTextBox extender, with a FilterType of either "Custom, Numbers" or just "Numbers".  The first choice is for when you want to be able to specify decimal points and negative numbers.  In that case you must also specify the ValidChars attribute with something like "-.". This will stop a user from entering characters that are not going to make up a valid number such as -123.45  . Note that it does not stop the user from entering the '-' & '.' in incorrect places e.g. "2-..-3" can still be entered.  You will need the validators mentioned in other answers to catch these cases.

```
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbe" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="numbersOnlyTextBox"         
    FilterType="Custom, Numbers"
    ValidChars="-." />
```

Or

```
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbe" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="numbersOnlyTextBox"         
    FilterType="Numbers" />
```